# onicecandidate returns null candidate when trying to connect for the first time

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, video-conferencing

`peerconnection.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;`

I have handler for onicecandidate

```
function handleIceCandidate(event) {
    console.log('icecandidate event: ', event);
    if (event.candidate) {
        sendMessage({
            type: 'candidate',
            label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
            candidate: event.candidate.candidate
        });
    } else {
        console.log('End of candidates.');    
    }
}
```

The above is the handler function to add the ice candidate. But when calling for the first time after starting socket server it seems the **event.candidate = null** but then when I refresh the page and try again it works with valid candidate in **event.candidate**

Comment: Are u solve it?

Comment: Hi @OliverD the issue was not with the null candidate. At the initial connection it was sending the offer before  properly setting the local description. We fixed the issue by handling the same. Hence the question statement is bit wrong in itself.